# Divide the columns with another columns without hard coding it

Tags: r

I have a below case where i need to divide col b and c with col d. Is it possible to achieve without hard coding it

```
> asd <- data.frame(a = c("A","B"), b = c(1,2), c= c(4,5))
> asd
  a b c
1 A 1 4
2 B 2 5
> asd$d <- asd$b + asd$c
> asd
  a b c d
1 A 1 4 5
2 B 2 5 7
```

Expected out (**col b is col b / col d and col c is col c / col d**)

```
asd
  a     b           c        d       
1 A 0.2000000 0.8000000      5 
2 B 0.2857143  0.7142857     7
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "without hard coding it". In what way do you need it to generalize?

Comment: I mean, we can do this, by creating another 2 columns and then deleting col b and col c. But what if there are many such columns :)

Answer (score 5):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
asd %>% mutate(across(b:c, ~ ./d))
  a         b         c d
1 A 0.2000000 0.8000000 5
2 B 0.2857143 0.7142857 7
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, this scales up nicely to any number of columns:

```
cols_to_divide = c("b", "c")
divisor = rowSums(asd[cols_to_divide ])
asd[cols_to_divide ] = asd[cols_to_divide ] / divisor
asd
#   a         b         c
# 1 A 0.2000000 0.8000000
# 2 B 0.2857143 0.7142857
```